# Get return value of function and use in if statement

Tags: function, lua, return

I have a function that returns a boolean value.
Now, outside of the function, I only want to continue if the return value of the function is true.
I tried using an if statement but i dont know how to correctly check for it.

Comment: I found the solution. I just had to call the function and the return value would obviously be the result that i can use in the if-statement.

Comment: And since the function returns a boolean, you can skip the comparison as well and end up with `if func() then`